# Get image dimensions inside ng-repeat and put it in ng-repeat item | AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm rendering some scope of objects via ng-repeat.

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products">
    <td><img ng-src="{{product.img_thumb}}" ng-model="product.imgSize" img-dimensions-bind-directive></td>
</tr>
```

How I can get image `clientWidth` and `clientHeight`and put it in object `product.imgSize` inside ng-repeat?

What `img-dimensions-bind-directuve` should be?

Currently I have:

```
app.directive('imgDimensionsBindDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            element.bind('load', function() {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(element[0].clientWidth);
                // but how bind height ??
                // element[0].clientHeight
            });
        }
    }
});
```

On output each `product` must have `imgSize.width` and `imgSize.height` params.

Or maybe it is possible to do with `onload` function?

Please help.

Comment: Post what you currently have for `img-dimensions-bind-directive`

Comment: Add a load handler inside directive. `link` function exposes the element

Comment: Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about binding to product object directly without any additional ngModel. Like this:

```
app.directive('imgDimensionsBindDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            product: '=imgDimensionsBindDirective'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('load', function() {
                scope.product.imgSize = {
                    width: element[0].clientWidth,
                    height: element[0].clientHeight
                };
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and HTML then:

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products">
    <td><img ng-src="{{product.img_thumb}}" img-dimensions-bind-directive="product"></td>
</tr>
```

**Demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/8xGZ8LrKL6NB22ZX8Mpz?p=preview

Comment: btw, `scope.$apply()` isn't necessary in this case.

Comment: Maybe, I added it because in demo I print `{{products | json}}` and it will not be updated without new digest. But yea, `project` objects are anyway get imgSize object without $apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the dimensions as a json string.

```
app.directive('imgDimensionsBindDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            element.bind('load', function() {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(angular.toJson({width: element[0].clientWidth,height:  element[0].clientHeight}));
            });
        }
    }
});
```